# python: best way to improve a function with a error message

Tags: python, performance, error-handling, coding-style

i wish to improve the following function. Given a Pixel data types in [GDAL](https://gdal.org/api/index.html#raster-api) (ex: "Int16") resturn a code number.

```
def GDAL_data_type(dataType):
    dtypes = {
        "Unknown": 0,
        "Byte": 1,
        "UInt16": 2,
        "Int16": 3,
        "UInt32": 4,
        "Int32": 5,
        "Float32": 6,
        "Float64": 7,
        "CInt16": 8,
        "CInt32": 9,
        "CFloat32": 10,
        "CFloat64": 11
        }
    return dtypes[dataType]

GDAL_data_type("Int16")
3
```

I wish to insert a error message in the function where if you type a dataType different, the error message say:

```
raise SystemExit('Pixel data type no recognized %s' % dataType)
```

I wish to ask the best way to insert this error message in my function. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you wanting to raise `SystemExit`?

Comment: Don't raise `SystemExit` or angry developers like me will come and murder you in your sleep

Comment: @Gianni you probably want something like `raise KeyError("wasn't found!")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the dictionary lookup in a try block, catch the keyerror exception, and raise your own from the catch block:

```
try:
  return dtypes[dataType]
except KeyError:
  raise ...
```

**EDIT**

Or more fully:

```
def GDAL_data_type(dataType):
    dtypes = {
        "Unknown": 0,
        "Byte": 1,
        "UInt16": 2,
        "Int16": 3,
        "UInt32": 4,
        "Int32": 5,
        "Float32": 6,
        "Float64": 7,
        "CInt16": 8,
        "CInt32": 9,
        "CFloat32": 10,
        "CFloat64": 11
        }
    try:
        return dtypes[dataType]
    except KeyError:
        raise ...
```

Comment: @DimaRudnik, thanks. Some followers say that raise SystemExit is not the best choise. Do you suggest one?

Comment: @Gianni, it depends on how bad the lookup error is. I think the advice Jakob Bowyer is pretty sound. You can always take a look at the [standard exeptions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) and raise another.

Comment: @Gianni I would suggest `ValueError`: "Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value"

Comment: Of course a custom exception would be appropriate, too. For example `class UnknownDataType(Exception): pass`

Answer (score 0):

You could either put your return statement in a try block and catch any exception Or you could  create a `default dictionary` and put all the values in the `default dictionary`.The `default dictionary` returns zero if the element is not there in it.

You can initialize a default dictionary like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
dtypes=defaultdict(int)
dtypes.update({
        "Unknown": 0,
        "Byte": 1,
        "UInt16": 2,
        "Int16": 3,
        "UInt32": 4,
        "Int32": 5,
        "Float32": 6,
        "Float64": 7,
        "CInt16": 8,
        "CInt32": 9,
        "CFloat32": 10,
        "CFloat64": 11
        })
```

You can retrieve the value by using the `get()` method. If you try to check for a value not in the dictionary it would return **0** and you could check if its returning zero and print an error message

Example:

`dtypes.get("Int16",0)` would return 3

`dtypes.get("xyz",0)` would return 0, because 0 is set as the default value to return when the key is not found

You can use an `if` condition to check the value and print an error message if its `0`.This would help you to set your own custom error message or do any other processing you might need to do

Comment: You know that you can check for a missing key with `if dataType not in dtypes`?

Comment: No need for a `defaultdict` with `get`!